# Tensorflow: How to apply a regularizer on a tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor, regularized

I am implementing a model in Tensorflow 2, and I want to apply a penalization on a tensor (multiplication from two layers' outputs) in my model.
I am used to use regularization on layers (kernel, bias or activity regularization).

I could build a custom layer that only has an activity regularization, but I am hopping that there is a simpler solution to add regularization to a tensor.

I saw this code in [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/Regularizer):

```
regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.L2(2.)
tensor = tf.ones(shape=(5, 5))
regularizer(tensor)
```

Which outputs:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=50.0>
```

But does this only compute the regularization value or it also add it to my model's loss?

Or would adding `self.add_loss(tf.keras.regularizers.L2(2.)(tensor))` in my call function work?

How would you add a penalty on a tensor?

It is my first question on stackoverflow so sorry if I didn't ask in the good place.

Answer (score 0):

No, the regularizer classes pretty much only handle the computation of the penalty itself. E.g. the source code for the L2 regularizer has

```
def __call__(self, x):
    return self.l2 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x))
```

and there is also nothing in `__init__` that points at any "housekeeping" work. However, `activity_regularizer` is actually an argument for the base `Layer` class so any subclassed layer should be able to handle it by default, meaning it should be easy to write a custom layer (you essentially only have to write the `call` method which sounds like a one-liner in your case).

You may even be able to use a [`Lambda`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda?hl=en) layer to avoid having to write any sub-classing code, since these also inherit from `Layer`. However, the docs mention that there are some issues with `Lambda` regarding saving and loading models...

Comment: Thanks for your time! I will subclass keras Layer class then ...

Comment: Is this the correct way to create the class: 
```class TensorRegularizer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """A layer that add an activity penalty on a tensor."""
    def __init__(self,
                 activity_regularizer,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer, **kwargs)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs```